# Lightroom/Photoshop pricing confusion

Tags: lightroom, photoshop, licensing, creative-cloud

I am considering getting Lightroom (and/or Photoshop) priavtely as I use them at work and really enjoy them. I am, however, evry confused by the pricing on the adobe page. In particular, how can the bundle of both programs be half as expensive, e.g., as Photoshop alone? Is there any catch in the bundle? Less features in the programs, etc.?

[image: Licence Confusion]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has absolutely nothing to do with photography.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no catch. PS is the same software you will find in Photo subscription. The only difference is Photo subscription include as you can see LR Classic, LR, PS with 20GB of cloud space. And LR subscription is with 1TB cloud space (and by my understanding include only LR and not LR Classic).

IMHO PS subscription follow the price formula of Adobe for single application plans.

Maybe there is some difference about number of included Adobe Stock images in different subscriptions.

P.S. Some time ago there was text that the price of Photo package is temporary and as far as I remember there was try from Adobe to raise the price but customers voices stop them from doing it.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure what you mean by LR Classic, though, don't see a product of that name on the page. Still, don't get why PS alone costs 23,79€, but together w Lightroom only 11,89€. Why would ever get it standalone then?

Comment: @EluciusFTW, you can check this link for the difference between LR Classic and LR CC: https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop-lightroom-classic/lightroom-cc-vs-lightroom-classic.html